# Unformatted XML Nodes When Adding To Existing File

Tags: xml, formatting

I am having issues trying to maintain my formatting within an XML file whenever I add a new node to the file.  For example, if I create the XML file initially from scratch, the formatting is correct as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Settings>
    <DropBoxLocation></DropBoxLocation>
    <ServerName></ServerName>
    <DatabaseName></DatabaseName>
    <Username></Username>
    <Password></Password>
    <OnlineFilename></OnlineFilename>
    <OfflineFilename></OfflineFilename>
    <EftposFilename></EftposFilename>
    <BankFilename></BankFilename>
    <POSFilename></POSFilename>
    <UnprocessedFilename></UnprocessedFilename>
    <SalesFilename></SalesFilename>
    <FileReadDelay></FileReadDelay>
  </Settings>
</Data>
```

However, whenever I add a new nodes to the pre-existing file, I end up with the following unformatted entries at the bottom of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Settings>
    <DropBoxLocation></DropBoxLocation>
    <ServerName></ServerName>
    <DatabaseName></DatabaseName>
    <Username></Username>
    <Password></Password>
    <OnlineFilename></OnlineFilename>
    <OfflineFilename></OfflineFilename>
    <EftposFilename></EftposFilename>
    <BankFilename></BankFilename>
    <POSFilename></POSFilename>
    <UnprocessedFilename></UnprocessedFilename>
    <SalesFilename></SalesFilename>
    <FileReadDelay></FileReadDelay>
<SEOFilename></SEOFilename><LBossFilename></LBossFilename><ProcessesFilename></ProcessesFilename></Settings>
</Data>
```

My code to add a new node looks like this:

```
Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode

        MyXML.PreserveWhitespace = True

        Try
            MyXML.Load(SettingsXMLFile)
            MyXMLNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("//Data/Settings/" & ElementName)
            If Not MyXMLNode Is Nothing Then
                MyXMLNode.InnerText = ElementValue.ToString
                MyXML.Save(SettingsXMLFile)
            Else
                Dim XMLRoot As XmlElement = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("//Data/Settings")
                Dim XMLChild As XmlElement = MyXML.CreateElement(ElementName)
                XMLChild.InnerText = ElementValue
                XMLRoot.AppendChild(XMLChild)
                MyXML.Save(SettingsXMLFile)
            End If

            MyXMLNode = Nothing
            MyXML = Nothing
```

Wondering if someone can assist as I'm not sure what causes the file to drop formatting.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has any feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I was trying to update an existing (well-formed) xml file on a server.

The code example below is in a javascript function

```
...
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
xml += '<root>';
xml += '<child_A>Hello World</child_A>';
xml += '<child_B>Good World</child_B>';
xml += '</root>';
...
```

Then in the ASP file, I tried to use the appendChild method to add the new xml node to root node of my existing xml. The new node added to my xml file is unformatted, just like your example. Everything attached together like a long string :(

After hours of research and trial & error...

The solution to my problem...

```
...
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
xml += ' <root>';
xml += '   <child_A>Hello World</child_A>';
xml += '   <child_B>Good World</child_B>';
xml += ' </root>';
...
```

Putting space in the string !?! It works for me on FireFox anyway, I need to make sure it works for IE as well.

I hope this help.